# Create Struts2 select tag with Enumsubset

Tags: struts2, ognl, html-select

I have a JSP page and I use Struts to build my select tag. The JSP code is the following:

```
<s:select
    required="true"
    name="form.tipologia"
    label="%{getText('Enum.label')}"
    list="@it........Enum@values()"
    listKey="name()"
    listValue="getText('Enum.' + name())"
    headerKey=""
    headerValue="%{getText('Enum.')}" 
/>
```

This code produces me a select field with my Enum constants. 
What I want to do is to create the field with only a subset of the Enum.
How can I do it? Is it possible?

Comment: Subset based on what? Do you want to check some condition?

Comment: ´list="@it........Enum@values()"´ takes all the values of my enum, i want to take all except one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OGNL projection for this.

```
<s:select list="@it..Enum@values().{? #this != @it..Enum@ENUM_TO_EXCLUDE}" />
```

This will create a subset of all enum values except that one that you want to exclude.

If comparing enums doesn't work then you can compare strings.

```
<s:select list="@it..Enum@values().{? #this.toString() != 'ENUM_TO_EXCLUDE'}" />
```

Comment: Thx for reply...i tryied but i get an exception "could not be resolved as a collection"

Comment: @Emaborsa: Have you correctly typed the enum value to exclude?

Comment: @Emaborsa: Yep you can compare enum strings also.

Comment: should `values().{? #this != @it..Enum@RIUTILIZZO}` also work? actually it doesn't